# Spring Data JPA: perform all CRUD operation without defining any Repository interface in application

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

In my application, we are using Spring Data JPA so that we do not have to write all basic CRUD  operations by hand.

But, now we are adding our CUSTOM DAO layer, in which we will have all CRUD operations per entity and it will delegate call to underlying Spring Data JPA.

For example,
Entity : User.java
DAO  : UserDao.java
Impl : UserDaoImpl.java

In UserDaoImpl.java, we have defined APIs like

1. save(User)
2. delete(User)
3. findUser(id)

above apis delegate call to Spring Data JPA like

```
public User save(USER user) {
userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Above is working fine but I need to create **Dao** and **DaoImpl** for every entity just like as I defined Spring Data JPA repository. I want to avoid this.

I want to implement some GENERIC **DAO** and **DAOImpl** like

```
public GenericDaoImpl<T,ID>{
    public User save(T) {
        ${SPRING_DATA_JPA_REPOSITORY}.save(T);
      } 
}
```

**${SPRING_DATA_JPA_REPOSITORY}** where I stuck, In **GenericDaoImpl**, I want to get Spring Data JPA's underlying some repository bean to which I can delegate call to all CRUD operation.

Any idea ?

I knew, **SimpleJpaRepository** performs all CRUD operations, but I do not know how can I use it in my **GenericDaoImpl**.

Please suggest.

Comment: One question why?! Why are you wrapping your data access layer in another data access layer?1 You seem to only make things more complex.

Comment: one reason is I want to add technology agonstic layer which will hide all ORM layer inside it, so that upper layer like Service layer or manager layer will use my added DAO layer instead of any specific DAL. so that , in future if I change ORM framework, my service layer will intact and only I need to change my added DAO layer

Comment: Switching ORMs (like databases) and expect to keep your services or remainder of the software unmodified is an illusion. When using Spring Data JPA why should your service know that it is JPA? It only has an interface to talk to. When you switch either create your own implementation of that interface or use another Sprnig Data project. You still have the same problem you are only adding an extra layer of complexity.